# Grape API + Active Record Wrapping Transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, transactions, grape-api

We have grape API but I wonder if we can wrap it with active record transaction every time we do request.

In active record to do transaction, we can do something like this:

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    # do select
    # do update
    # do insert
 end
```

**How can I wrap it into grape API?**

As far as i know, in Grape API we can implement *before* method and *after* method.

```
class API < Grape::API
   before do
     # ????? Need to implement code here to begin active record transaction
     # this suppose to begin active record transaction
   end
   after do
     # ????? Need to implement code here to end active record transaction
     # this suppose to end active record transaction
   end
end
```

Comment: hope anybody can answer this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ccdeb43d2e06fb87c1fb84e979c4f7775e7ed105/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L215) of `transaction` block in active record, you should do something like:

```
class API < Grape::API

  before do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.begin_transaction
  end

  after do
    begin
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.commit_transaction unless @error
    rescue Exception
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.rollback_transaction
      raise
    end
  end

  rescue_from :all do |e|
    @error = e
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.rollback_transaction
    # handle exception...
  end

end
```

Comment: wow, thanks. i will give it a try.. just wait before i accept your answer.